# Undefined reference to symbol, DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, debian

I'm trying to compile the [Lotech framework](https://github.com/ianmaclarty/lotech) under Debian Jessie, but I'm can't seem to get past a specific point in compilation. I've searched the error messages that come up, and almost all of them seem to be resolved by installing or linking a missing dependency, but I can't figure out what that dependency is in this situation.

```
cp buildtmp.linux/liblt.a linux/
cd clients/glfw/ && make LTCFLAGS="-O3 -DNDEBUG -DLTLINUX " && cp ltclient ../../
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jake/Desktop/copy-lotech-master/clients/glfw'
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -DLTLINUX  -I../../linux/include -L../../linux ltclient.cpp \
        -o ltclient -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ../../linux/liblt.a ../../linux/libpng.a ../../linux/libz.a ../../linux/liblua.a ../../linux/libvorbis.a ../../linux/libbox2d.a ../../linux/libglfw.a ../../linux/libGLEW.a ../../linux/libopenal.a ../../linux/libcurl.a -lX11 -lGL wrap_memcpy.o -Wl,--wrap=memcpy
/usr/bin/ld: ../../linux/libopenal.a(helpers.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [ltclient] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jake/Desktop/copy-lotech-master/clients/glfw'
make: *** [ltclient] Error 2
```

Answer (score 6):

For me this does the trick

> set (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE} -ldl")

Useful links

[Link1](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/static-library-link-order-td4674728.html)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934549/very-strange-linker-behavior)

[Link3 <- Cmake how to find libraries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)

[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796353/cmake-linking-problem)

[Link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274529/building-project-involving-cmake-how-do-i-make-it-aware-of-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

DSO means Dynamic Shared Object. Add the option "-lpthread" works for me.

Comment: when you way "works for me", do you actually mean you reproduced the asker's exact problem scenario and solved it in this way? Or are you referring to a separate problem that you were personally facing? Gelldur's answer involves linking to a DLL-related library, and the asker's error message refers to a DLL-related function. I can't see how libpthread would fix a missing DLL symbol.

Comment: Yes, I got the error message as the asker's. The error was gone after I added "-lpthread" option in linking stage.

Comment: Interesting. If you have more insight into why this error occurs and why this fixes it, that would be a great addition to your answer.